# Endeca Dimension count

Tags: endeca, experience-manager

I am using Endeca experience manager and need the dimension count values. for example: brand.name dimension in discover application has individual value count for canon, kodak. I need the total count of brand.name in the header.

Please find below the screenshot for better picture

![screenshot image of discover navigation][10]

Comment: Can't see the image so not 100% sure about the question but I think you want to enable `Compute Refinement Statistics` on the brand dimension. This is easily done through Developer Studio.

Comment: Hi, compute refinement statistics is already enabled in the discover application. I am not able to post a picture. So explaining it detail with reference to discover application. I have Category Dimension in the left side navigation. I have count for Bags and Cases as 665 and Cameras as 4951 and I need the total of 665+4951=5616 records in the Category dimension. As of now it is not having the values in the discover application.

Comment: If the flag is enabled you should be able to see it by adding the `refinement.count` into the jsp page.